# Read file from wcf project folder which are hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am new in WCF.

I am trying to read data from WCF project folder's file within the same project, which are hosted on iis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the location of executing application:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

in order to access the directory you can use this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

then you can reach the directory like this:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(path1,path2,...)
```

Comment: I am reaching the .dll file ,but can't read file.                                                                                  I am showing structure of  file in my project.                                                                       Demo Project -> Xssdd -> filename

Comment: dear @PawanKumarNishad. unfortunately i couldn't understand what you want but i update the answer. hope it could help.

Comment: This is the correct answer, you need to combine the executing application directory and combine the path parts to your filename directory.